# Merge two lists in order to get charaster list in r

Tags: r, list, ggplot2, dplyr

I would need help in order to create a Value list takend by the ggplot function `(scale_fill_manual(values = c())`

In one hand I have a list of color such as :

```
color_list=c("blue" "red" "green")
```

and in another hand I have a list of names such as :

```
names_list=c("A","B","C")
```

and I would like to :

1. Merge those two lists in order to get a vector :

   The_vector<- c("A"="blue","B"="red","C"="green")
2. Add into `The_vector` a new element : `"D"=grey`

The_vector should then look like: `c("A"="blue","B"="red","C"="green","D"="grey")`
or in print format like :

```
A      B       C       D
"blue"  "red"  "green" "grey"
```

Does someone have an idea, please?

I will then use the vector within the function such as :

```
scale_fill_manual(values = The_vector)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the two vectors are of the same length and in the same order, we can use `setNames`

```
new_color_list <- setNames(color_list, names_list)
new_color_list
    A       B       C 
 "blue"   "red" "green"
```

or `names` on the same object

```
names(color_list) <- names_list
```

Now, we can concatenate

```
c(new_color_list, c(D = 'grey'))
   A       B       C       D 
 "blue"   "red" "green"  "grey"
```

or assign new element

```
new_color_list['D'] <- 'grey'
new_color_list
      A       B       C       D 
 "blue"   "red" "green"  "grey"
```

Answer (score 2):

A variant of `setNames` (but @akrun's answer is recommended)

```
> `names<-`(color_list, names_list)
      A       B       C 
 "blue"   "red" "green"
```